# Python - How to create edges in ArangoDB

Tags: python, arangodb, pyarango

I am using pyArango to handle by database operations. I have already created a graph and now I want add an edge in the graph.

So what are the methods from pyArango suitable for performing the mentioned task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the link() function of a graph:

http://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/graph.html#pyArango.graph.Graph.link

```
edge = g.link("myEdgesCollection", doc1, doc2, {})
```

or the links()/save() function of an edge document:
http://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/document.html#pyArango.document.Edge.links

```
edge.links(doc1, doc2)
```